# How to configure firebase version 9.19.1 on your react-native application?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, variable-length

I am using firebase version 9.19.1 on my react-native application and now its giving me error problem with my application about the length. I need some help with my configuration file for using firebase version 9.19.1. How to i fix this length error problem for using this version on my react-native application?

```
// package.json

{
  "name": "eshopmobile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "expo": "~48.0.10",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "firebase": "^9.19.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


// firebase.js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import * as firebase from "firebase";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "*****",
  authDomain: "eshopmobile-fb508.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "eshopmobile-fb508",
  storageBucket: "eshopmobile-fb508.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "734223583165",
  appId: "1:734223583165:web:6849ecf86323894686b4d4"
};



  // initialize firebase
  let app;

  if(!firebase.apps.length) {
    app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
  

 // const auth = firebase.auth()
  
  export {firebase};
```